# Getting RabbitMQ connection issues when connecting with SSL

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I get the following exception while connecting to a server on port 8071. I was told SSL is configured on port 8071 due to which the connection is blocked but the error message does not explicitly tell anything about SSL handshake failing etc.

```
Attempting to connect to: auslabrmq1.abc.xyz.com:8071
16:41:07.012 [springListenerContainerCSWF-5] ERROR org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:702)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2073)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2047)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2027)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:403)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1787)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1768)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.initialize(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:373)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1104)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1218)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:471)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:315)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:164)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:596)
```

Can anybody help me understand why exactly this may be happening?

XML bean configuration that I am using is:

```
<bean id="clientConnectionFactorySSL"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitConnectionFactoryBean">
        <property name="useSSL" value="true" />
        <property name="sslAlgorithm" value="TLSv1.2"/>
        <property name="keyStoreType" value="PKCS12"/>
        <property name="trustStoreType" value="JKS"/>
        <property name="skipServerCertificateValidation" value="false"/>
        </bean>


    <!-- CachingConnectionFactory -->
    <bean id="cachingConnectionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg value = "clientConnectionFactorySSL"/>
        <property name="virtualHost" value="XXXX" />
        <property name="host" value="XXX-XXX" />
        <property name="port" value="8071" />
        <property name="username" value="username"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        </bean>
```

Comment: Is my issue related to the below mentioned in any way? 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/840

Comment: No, it is not related to that issue. My best guess is that port is not amqp protocol - you should look at the server log. You should ask such questions on the rabbitmq-users Google Group - the RabbitMQ engineers monitor that more often than here.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for your quick response again. I have posted the question on google group as well. 8071 is a amqp protocol as our MQ team confirmed that other applications are communicating on that same port.

Comment: connStart =
                    (AMQP.Connection.Start) connStartBlocker.getReply(handshakeTimeout/2).getMethod(); 

This call seems to be failing. I am not sure why

Comment: The key and trust store types are only used if you actually specify a path to the stores. When you don't specify those, the context is initialized with no key managers and the default trust managers `sslContext.init(null, trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), null);`.

Comment: You can debug SSL handshaking with `-Djavax.net.debug=all`.